# what does $\alpha$ signify in finite fields modular arithmetic

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, primitive-roots

Say

$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{2}\left [ x \right ]}{x^{2}+x+1}=\left \{0,1,\alpha ,1+\alpha  \right \}$

is a finite field with its elements listed. I am finding it difficult to understand what it means to have $\alpha$ as residue class of $x$ mod $x^{2}+x+1$ here.

I know how to generate field elements using primitive poly by successive multiplication of ring variable(say x).

If I use $p={{x}^{6}}+{{x}^{4}}-{{x}^{2}}+x+1$, I get $x+1$, so is it in $1+\alpha$ class? Why it can't be just represented in terms of $x$?

Comment: Of course you could use $x$, but introducting $\alpha$ was done in order to differentiate $x$ from its equivalence class, $[x]$, under the above quotient map. Formally $x$ is not even in your new ring, only its equivalence class $[x]$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is needed a more thorough study in quotient rings in general, and in particular quotients of polynomial rings.

In this particular case we have simply that $\;\alpha:=x+I\;$ , with $\;I:=\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\;$ , so it is just the coset corresponding to $\;x\;$ modulo the ideal generated by that irreducible quadratic in $\;\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ , and it is thus *a root* of the quadratic in the given quotient (field), since

$$\alpha^2+\alpha+1=(x^2+I)+(x+I)+(x+I)=(x^2+x+1)+I=I=\overline 0=\;\text{The zero in}\;$$

the quotient ring

How to work with it? Very simple:

$$\alpha^2=-\alpha-1=\alpha+1\pmod 2\;,\;\;\text{so for example}$$

$$\alpha\cdot(\alpha+1)=\alpha^2+\alpha=(\alpha+1)+\alpha=2\alpha+1=1$$

so in this case we get that in our field with four element we get $\;\alpha^{-1}=\alpha+1\;$.

Remember! You always work with arithmetic modulo $\;2\;$ (or, in general, modulo the prime you're working with)

Comment: hm...$\alpha$=x+I makes good sense...I agree I need to learn quotient rings more.

Comment: I also figured out that $\alpha=x+1+I$ will also work but I think $x+I$ exists for all irreducible polynomials, hence its safe to presume this.

Comment: @Rorschach It would be the very same (isomorphic) field, as $\;\alpha+1\;$ is the second root of the quadratic $\;x^2+x+1\;$